# Strange behavior of material-ui when component is inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to split my code in more functions inside react functional components, so it's clearer to read and maintain the code, ie:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyledExchangeRateProvider } from "./styles";
import useUpdateRates from "../../hooks/useUpdateRates";
import {
    FormControl,
    InputLabel,
    MenuItem,
    Select,
    TextField
} from "@material-ui/core";

export default function ExchangeRateProvider() {
    // rates hook
    const ratesContext = useUpdateRates();
    const rates = ratesContext.state.rates;

    // update rate on component did mount
    useEffect(() => {
        async function updateRates() {
            if (!rates) {
                await ratesContext.updateRate();
            }
        }
        updateRates();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    // save input values
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        country: "VES",
        amount: "",
        total: ""
    });

    // change values
    const handleChange = event => {
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };

    function Amount() {
        return (
            <TextField
                name="amount"
                variant="filled"
                label="Amount"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={values.amount}
                fullWidth
            />
        );
    }

    function Country() {
        return (
            <FormControl fullWidth variant="filled" className="input">
                <InputLabel id="Country">Country</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="Country"
                    id="country"
                    name="country"
                    value={values.country}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                >
                    <MenuItem value="ARS">Argentina</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="BRL">Brazil</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="INR">India</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="VES">Venezuela</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="ZAR">South Africa</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        );
    }

    return (
        <StyledExchangeRateProvider>
            <Amount />
            <Country />
        </StyledExchangeRateProvider>
    );
}
```

In this code, I'm separating in functions what I'll render in this component, so, ie, the `Amount` function returns a `material-ui` TextField. It will return more things, but for simplicity of this question, let's consider just this.

This code renders well, and all elements are shown. However, when I type something in the TextField, the cursor moves away from the TextField each caracter I type.

If I move the `<TextField ... />` away from the `Amount` function and put it directly in the React Component return (switch the `<Amount />` for `<TextField ... />`), the TextField works fine.

I've made a CodeSandBox with the behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-brattain-r4irj

My question is: why does it happen and how to fix it maintaining the code separated in functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move Amount and  Country Components outside of ExchangeRateProvider and pass data via props. The Issue is because on each render the functions are being recreated